# UISwitch Value change state issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have used `UISwitch` in my application with `valueChanged` target like below code.
This switch is in my `UITableView`

```
settingsTableCell.androidSwitchSmall.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchStateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)


@objc func switchStateChanged(_ mjSwitch: MJMaterialSwitch) {
    if self.lastSwitchState == mjSwitch.isOn {
        return
    }
    self.lastSwitchState = mjSwitch.isOn
    print(mjSwitch.isOn, mjSwitch.tag, "Small")
    self.changeTrackStatus()
}
```

And I am changing the value of Switch inside the target method. So it is again calling `switchStateChanged` method.

But I want to call `switchStateChanged` this method only if user changes the switch state.

What could be the best way.

How I can distinguish between weather user changed the switch state or switch state is changed programmatically.

Comment: `UISwitch.setOn(mjSwitch)(true, animated: false)`

Answer (score 0):

Follow The Steps.

> Step - 1

Make a variable Inside the `TabelView Cell`

```
var Btn1 : (()->())?
```

> Step - 2

Create the Action Of UIButton inside the `TabelViewCell` And call above `Variable`.

```
@IBAction func cellbtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Btn1?()
 }
```

> Step - 3

Declare a `Bool` variable and Your `Function` in Your `View Controller`

```
var IsSwitchOn = false

 func switchStateChanged(_ mjSwitch: MJMaterialSwitch) {
    if self.IsSwitchOn {
        return
    }
    self.IsSwitchOn = True
    print(mjSwitch.isOn, mjSwitch.tag, "Small")
    self.changeTrackStatus()
}
```

> Step - 4

Call this in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as! YourCell

cell.Btn1 = {
              () in
              Self.switchStateChanged()
        }
```

Hope This Works.

Answer (score 0):

You must send action programmatically, 
You can use the following extension

```
extension UISwitch {
    func set(on state: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {
        setOn(state, animated: animated)
        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use .touchUpInside . This will only trigger selector if user interacts with the switch .

```
settingsTableCell.androidSwitchSmall.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchStateChanged(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```